# Devise Views with Multiple Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, devise, ruby-on-rails-4, gravatar

I have two models, admins and users. I have set scoped views = true within devise.rb. I also have generated two different set of devise views. For some reason when I click on edit admin registration, it gives me an error

```
NoMethodError in Aregistrations#edit 
undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass
```

It highlights this:

```
<%= gravatar_for @user %>
```

and points to **"app/views/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb"**

In my **"config/initializer/devise.rb"** file it has:

```
config.scoped_views = true
```

In my **"config/routes.rb"** file I have

```
devise_for :admins, :controllers => {:registrations => "aregistrations"}
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"}, :path_prefix => 'd'
resources :users, :only =>[:show]
```

In my **"app/controllers/aregistrations_controller.rb"** I have

```
def update
  new_params = params.require(:admin).permit(:email, :username, :current_password, :password, :password_confirmation)
  change_password = true
  if params[:admin][:password].blank?
    params[:admin].delete("password")
    params[:admin].delete("password_confirmation")
    new_params = params.require(:admin).permit(:email, :username)
    change_password = false
  end

  @admin = Admin.find(current_admin.id)
  is_valid = false

  if change_password
    is_valid = @admin.update_with_password(new_params)
  else
    is_valid = @admin.update_without_password(new_params)
  end

  if is_valid
    set_flash_message :notice, :updated
    sign_in @admin, :bypass => true
    redirect_to after_update_path_for(@admin)
  else
    render "edit"
  end
end
```

In my views I have a devise folder - for the user model and an admins folder for the admin model.

In my **"app/views/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb"** I have

```
<%= gravatar_for @user %>
<a href="http://gravatar.com/emails">change</a></br></br></br></br>
```

I have it set up to edit your profile and your gravtar image for users only.

In my **"app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb"** file I have

```
<% if admin_signed_in? %>
<li><%= link_to "Edit Account", edit_admin_registration_path %></li>
<% else %> 
.....
<% end %>
```

Why does Devise look for the user gravatar when I click on the edit admins path and have scoped views on?

-------------------- edit
In my **"app/controllers/users_controller.rb" ** file

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
before_filter :authenticate_admin!, :except => [:show]

  def index
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find_by_username(params[:id])
    @reviews = @user.reviews.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved this with the help from another post [Override Devise Registrations Controller Two Times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20927586/override-devise-registrations-controller-two-times) I found that I needed to create a directory within my **"app/controllers"** directory. This is how you use the scoped controller:

**"app/controllers/admin/registrations_controller.rb"**

```
class Admin::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  #Your Code Here
end
```

I can leave my first controller and keep it for the users **"app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb"**

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  #Your Code Here
end
```

My **"config/routes.rb"** will look like:

```
devise_for :admins, :controllers => {:registrations => "admins/registrations"}
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"}
```

Comment: The tip to have subdirectory in app/controllers is key for setting up the scoped_views.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it the method in the User has not been established properly. Have you tried restarting your server so that the config loads properly?

Comment: you mean crtl c to stop the server and rails s to start it again? I've done that yes

Comment: Where have you defined @user?

Comment: I added my users_controller

Comment: I noticed it has to do something with changing the name of the registrations controller and using aregistrations_controller.rb instead of registrations_controller.rb. Im not sure how to make it work from there however