# Override Devise Registrations Controller Two Times?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have two models, User and Admin. I want to know if its possible to override Devise's Registrations Controller and have two custom Registrations Controllers - one for each model.

I know its possible to get what I want by overriding the registrations controller and I would just use If else statements although (correct me if I am wrong) I believe its better to avoid having many if else statements if possible.

You can see what I've done so far on another post - I have scoped views and it uses the wrong set of views for some reason. [Devise Views with Multiple Models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20913157/devise-views-with-multiple-models)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it's possible

---

**Routes**

When you generate Devise for both models, you'll have to add it to your routes:

```
#config/routes.rb
devise_for :users
devise_for :admin
```

Devise actually uses these routes to populate its arguments, one of which is the `controllers` argument:

```
#config/routes.rb
devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: "sessions", registrations: "registrations" }
devise_for :admin, controllers: { registrations: "admin/session" }
```

---

**Controllers**

This will allow you to create controllers to override the Devise default ones:

```
#app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
    #Your Code Here
end

#app/controllers/admin/registrations_controller.rb
class Admin::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
    #Your Code Here
end
```

Comment: Thank you! When using app/controllers/admin/registrations_controller.rb - do you have to always include the second overridden controller within a directory in the controllers directory? If so, does the directory you create (in this case admin) have to match the same name for the scoped view you are using?

Comment: Hi, what about overriding controllers two times for the same recource class? How to setup routes? with `devise_for` or only manually?

Comment: @MarcoSanfilippo Were you able to override controllers two times for the same recource class? I am trying to do the same - but with no luck!